# Dictionary with Vector3 as key, GameObject as value

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting "object instance not set to an instance object"

```cs
private Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> wallPositions;

    void Start()
    {
        size = 6;
        HalfMaze = new GameObject("Half Maze");
        traversed = new bool[size, size, size];
        Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> wallPositions = new Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject>();
        GenerateGrid();
    }
```

```cs
//in some function
        foreach (Transform child in HalfMaze.transform) {
            //Debug.Log("hi2");
            foreach (Transform grandchild in child) {
                //Debug.Log(grandchild.gameObject.name);
                if (!(grandchild.position.x == -0.5f || grandchild.position.x == -0.5f + size || grandchild.position.y == -0.5f || grandchild.position.y == -0.5f + size || grandchild.position.z == 0 || grandchild.position.z == -0.5f + size)) {
                    wallPositions[grandchild.position] = grandchild.gameObject; //issue is here
                    //Debug.Log("hi");
                }
            }
        }
```

The inside of the if statement in the 2nd block of code is causing the issue during runtime. I'm not sure why I'm getting the issue because grandchild.gameObject is not null.

Comment: @hijinxbassist this is not true. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-8.0)

Comment: @hijinxbassist You can index a non-existant key if you are using the setter part of the indexer, like op is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are redeclaring the wallPositions variable inside the Start method. Remove the type declaration Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> when initializing the wallPositions variable in the Start method.

Replace this line:

```
Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> wallPositions = new Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject>();
```

with this:

```
wallPositions = new Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject>();
```

see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your variables before you can use them, including dictionaries.

```
private Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject> wallPositions = new();
```